# Radio buttons failing to keep checked prop on manual page refresh using NextJs + Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I have a filters component in my NextJs app which has a group of radio buttons that help filter products based on price range. I have implemented the feature as follows:

```
const budget = [
  {
    id: "price_1",
    name: "price",
    min_price: 0,
    max_price: 100,
  },
  {
    id: "price_2",
    name: "price",
    min_price: 100,
    max_price: 500,
  },
  {
    id: "price_3",
    name: "price",
    min_price: 500,
    max_price: 1000,
  },
];

export default function Filters() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState(router.query.min_price || "");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      setMinPrice(router.query.min_price);
    }
  }, [router.query, router.isReady]);

  {
    budget.map((price) => {
      return (
        <div key={price.id} className="form-check mb-2">
          <input
            className="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name={`${price.name}`}
            id={price.id}
            onChange={(e) =>
              filterProducts(e, {
                min_price: price.min_price,
                max_price: price.max_price,
                filter: 1,
              })
            }
            defaultChecked={
              +router.query.min_price === +price.min_price ? true : false
            }
            defaultValue={price.min_price}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label medium" htmlFor={price.id}>
            GHS{price.min_price} - GHS{price.max_price}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The radio button gets checked on click/on change but when I manually refresh the page the checked prop doesn't stay and is removed from the currently selected radio button. I tried matching the min_price in the router.query object against the min price of the radio button to set the checked prop but it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong because I have not been able to find a solution for a whole week. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set the router's query whenever you make a change to the form.

Comment: Yes I do set them like this: ` router.push({
          pathname: router.pathname,
          query: updated_query_after_param_removed !== undefined ? updated_query_after_param_removed : { ...router.query, ...params }}, undefined, {shallow:true}) `

Comment: can you add that in your code then? so we know when this gets triggered